# Zod getter function?

Tags: typescript, zod

Is there any way to build the equivalent of a getter inside of a Zod object?

For example, in >=es5 you can do the following:

```
const me = {
   firstName: "Testy",
   lastName: "mcTestface",
   get myName() {return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`}
}
me.myName => "Testy mcTestface"
```

Comment: Are you asking about parsing something that has a getter, or adding a getter as a result of parsing (e.g. input is `{ firstName: "Testy", lastName: "mcTestface" }`, but after `.parse` it has the getter property)?

Comment: @Samathingamajig After parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Under "Comparison" [the zod documentation](https://zod.dev/?id=runtypes) states

> Runtypes
>
> https://github.com/pelotom/runtypes
>
> Good type inference support. They DO support readonly types, which Zod does not.

So zod does not support readonly properties.

---

That said this works fine:

```
import { z } from "zod";

const meUnknown: unknown = {
  firstName: "Testy",
  lastName: "mcTestface",
  get myName() {
    return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
  }
};

const MeSchema = z.object({
  firstName: z.string(),
  lastName: z.string(),
  myName: z.string()
});

const me = MeSchema.parse(meUnknown);
/* `me` has a type of:
{
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    myName: string;
}
*/

console.log(me.myName);
```

[See sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/red-monad-cw6c5y?file=/src/index.ts)

But, at the type level zod does not error when you do:

```
me.myName = 'something' // no type error here
```

Because, again, zod does not support readonly types.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the exact shape of the object you are trying to build, then you could use a `transform` to take your parsed data and wrap it up in an instance of a class with your readonly properties:

```js
class NamedThing {
  public constructor (
    public firstName: string,
    public lastName: string,
  ) {}
  
  public get myName() {
    return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
  }
}

const schema = z.object({
  firstName: z.string(),
  lastName: z.string(),
}).transform(
  ({ firstName, lastName }) => new NamedThing(firstName, lastName)
);

const obj = schema.parse({ lastName: 'Ever', firstName: 'Greatest' });
console.log(obj.myName); // 'Greatest Ever'
```